# Getting undefined when trying to create new array of objects from another array of objects using forEach(). TypeScript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, foreach

I'm trying to create a new array of objects from an array of objects. The original array consists of 3 KeyValues. date, startTime, and endTime. Going to be converted to a new array of objects of 2 KeyValues of startDate and endDate.

Below is my attempt, but the result came out undefined.

```
sendScheduleForm() {
        const dateArrForm = this.datetimeForm.value.datetime.forEach(
          (session: any) => {
            const schedule = {
              startDate: new Date(session.date + ' ' + session.startTime)
                .getTime()
                .toString(),
              endDate: new Date(session.date + ' ' + session.endTime)
                .getTime()
                .toString(),
            };
            // dateArrForm.push(schedule);
            return schedule;
          }
        );
        console.log(dateArrForm); // undefined
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use array `map` for this

```
sendScheduleForm() {
        const dateArrForm = this.datetimeForm.value.datetime.map(
          (session: any) => {
            const schedule = {
              startDate: new Date(session.date + ' ' + session.startTime)
                .getTime()
                .toString(),
              endDate: new Date(session.date + ' ' + session.endTime)
                .getTime()
                .toString(),
            };
            // dateArrForm.push(schedule);
            return schedule;
          }
        );
        console.log(dateArrForm); // new list
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you tried dateArrForm.push and commented that. It works fine for me.

```
const dateArrForm = []; 
    
this.datetimeForm.value.datetime.forEach(
    (session: any) => {
        const schedule = {
          startDate: new Date(session.date + ' ' + session.startTime)
            .getTime()
            .toString(),
          endDate: new Date(session.date + ' ' + session.endTime)
            .getTime()
            .toString(),
        };
        dateArrForm.push(schedule);
    }
);
    
console.log(dateArrForm);
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ez7cod?file=src/app/app.component.ts